# Bypassing Browser popup blocking when automatic session timeout occurs

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, popup-blocker

Please help regarding the following issue.

I have enabled the "Block popup" option in browser. We are doing a session validation using a background ajax call to check the session is active or not. If the session is not active for a desired interval a popup window  will come for notification.

Now comming to the problem . since the session notification popup is comming automatically without any client interaction, This popup is blocked by the browser. But if a client clicks anyother popup window in the form that popup window will not be blocked by the browser.

I want the session notification popup window also not to be blocked by the browser even if the browser "Block popup" option is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A popup blocker is used to block popups. If there was a way around it, it would be completely useless.

You can either:

1. Add an exception for your domain in your popup blocker's settings
2. Not use a popup for your notification but rather display it on the page itself through javascript

Comment: Hi Andreas,

Thanks for the clarification , but showing the notification as poup is client requirement. Do you know any javascript ways to achieve it. I tried with onclick function but it didnt worked.

Comment: Every popup blocker is different so I cannot answer your question; but most likely no, if there was a way the popup blocker would be useless since all the advertising companies would use that way to show the popups anyway.

Comment: can you help me answer this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232546/browser-window-popups-risks-and-special-features ?

Answer (score 2):

If the browser has blocked use of pop-ups in JavaScript, it has blocked them. There is no way you can force the browser to let them through.

You can always try creating a pop-up like element on your page, it won't force the user to deal with it first (except on your page) but will still 'look' correct.